# .net core3.0 MVC "Web サーバー 'IIS Express' に接続できませんでした。"

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, iis, asp.net-core

.Net Core 3.0を使用してMVC開発を行いたいのですが、下記エラーメッセージが表示され、画面を起動できません。
考えられる解決法などありますでしょうか。

**やりたいこと**
Visual Studio 2019を用いたMVCプロジェクトの起動。

**できないこと**
「デバッグの開始」「デバッグなしで開始」をクリックした際、`Web サーバー 'IIS Express' に接続できませんでした。`というメッセージが表示され、起動できません。（添付画像1）

**試したこと**
・プロジェクトの`.vs`ファイルの削除
→プロジェクトの「プロパティ」の「デバッグ」タブから、アプリ URLのポー番号（添付画像2の赤枠内）変更
（追記）
・[管理者として実行]オプションを使用してVisual Studioを開き、アプリケーションを実行。

**環境**
windows8.1
ASP.Net Core 3.0
Visual Studio 2019

**添付画像1**
[image: 起動時のエラーメッセージ]

**添付画像2**
[image: アプリ URLのポー番号の変更]

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio を管理者として起動していない可能性があります。

ここに注意事項が出ているので、対策を試してみてください。
[クイック スタート: Visual Studio を使用して初めての ASP.NET Core Web アプリを作成する](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/ide/quickstart-aspnet-core?view=vs-2019)

> **注意**
>
> **"Web サーバー 'IIS Express' に接続できませんでした"** というエラー メッセージ、または SSL 証明書に関するエラー メッセージが表示された場合は、Visual Studio を閉じます。 次に、右クリック コンテキスト メニューから **[管理者として実行]** オプションを使用して Visual Studio を開きます。 その後、アプリケーションをもう一度実行します。

---

あるいは IIS Express のインストール/起動がされていない場合とか？

他には IIS Express 以外の Webサーバーソフトが起動していて、それと競合しているとか。
またはファイアウォールとかウィルスチェックソフトで何か制限を掛けているとか。

英語の記事で詳しくは判らないのですが、何か関連がありそうなので書いておきます。
[ASP.NET Core on IIS Express - Empty error starting application](https://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2019/02/26/asp-net-core-iis-express-empty-error-starting-application.html)

必要無いかもしれませんが、IIS Expressのダウンロードリンク
[インターネット インフォメーション サービス (IIS) 10.0 エクスプレス](https://www.microsoft.com/ja-JP/download/details.aspx?id=48264)

Visual Studio Installerの個別のコンポーネントでIIS Expressにチェックが入っているか？というのもありますね。
[image: VisualStudioInstaller画像]

以下はIISの記事でIIS Expressとは違うということなので消し線します。
<s>以下は別のソフトのQ&A記事ですが、参考になるでしょう。

[Windows 8/8.1 での IIS および必要な IIS コンポーネントの有効化](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/ja/web-adaptor/latest/install/iis/enable-iis-8-components-server.htm)

[インストールして Windows 8 で 8 を IIS で PHP を構成する方法](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/help/2819022/how-to-install-and-configure-php-on-iis-8-in-windows-8)

[Windows 8.1以降の場合](https://jp.cybozu.help/ja/settings/browser/webinstall/iis85install/iis85_win81.html)

[Windows 10/8/7/Vista に IIS をインストール](https://creativeweb.jp/personal-site/iis/)</s>

ただ、こんな記事もあるので、IIS ExpressではなくIISでも出来るのかも。
[Visual Studio for ASP.NET Core の開発時 IIS サポート](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/development-time-iis-support?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

---

ちなみにWindows10でやってみたら出来ました。
手順途中のメニュー等に細かい違いはありましたが。
初回起動時は証明書関連の確認ダイアログ等も出てきますがOKにしてしまえば出来ました。

Windows10 Pro 64bit 1909
ASP.NET Core 3.1
Visual Studio Community 2019 16.4.5
上記スクリーンショットのように関連のワークロードやIIS Expressは入れてあります。
IIS は入っていません。

Comment: IISとIIS ExpressはJavaとJavaScriptぐらい違います…

Comment: そうだったんですか。じゃそもそもインストールされていなかったのですかね。